# How to create a vector of another class struc? (C++ 11)

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

I searched for a solution to my problem but find none, so i'm asking here.

A have a class with a public struct called equacao, and i want to create a vector of equacao in the main.cpp or in another class. But it gives an erro of :

```
error: 'equacao' does not name a type
```

Can somone help please?

tanks.

```
class algoritimoGenetico
{    
public:

    struct termo
    {
        std::uint_fast16_t atrazo : 6;
        std::uint_fast16_t colunaVariavel : 10;
        float expoente;
    };
    struct regresor
    {
        std::vector<termo> termos;
        std::uint_fast16_t coeficiente;
        bool divisor;
    };
    struct equacao
    {
        std::vector<regresor> regresores;
        std::uint_fast16_t maiorAtrazo;
        float aptidao;
        float erroQuadratico;

    };
```

And in the main.cpp i trying:

```
 algoritimoGenetico AG;

 std::vector<std::vector< AG.equacao > >  mat(40000, std::vector<AG.equacao> (7));
```

Comment: I think you want `algoritimoGenetico::equaco` rather than `AG.equacao` as `AG` is an instance of `algoritimoGenetico` and `equaco` is a nested type.

Comment: Move the nested class to another header and source files.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. All i need was to clean the project too. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of the *member*

```
std::vector< AG.equacao >
```

You actually would have a *scoped* struct

```
std::vector< algoritimoGenetico::equacao >
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. All i need was to clean the project too.